# A Problem about Line Broadening and Absorption coefficient

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, laser, absorption

I am reading my textbook, *Lasers* by Anthony E. Siegman, and I just could not understand a point he made.
In the chapter section about inhomogeneous broadening, he used a figure to show the transition from inhomogeneous broadening(Doppler Broadening in his example) to homogeneous broadening(pressure broadening), as shown below.
[image]

I have some trouble understanding why the absorption coefficient shows such dependence on pressure. The author points out that Doppler broadening dominants at low pressure and pressure broadening dominates at high pressure, causing the diagram to look like this. However, I do not know how absorption coefficient is related to these two types of broadening, and there seems to be no relevant content in the textbook. Could somebody explain this to me?
Thanks in advance for answering my question.

Edit: The caption to the figure says: (a) Apparatus using a tunable CO2 laser to measure absorption versus frequency in a variable-pressure CO2 cell, (b) Midband (peak) absorption versus gas pressure; and (c)linewidth versus pressure in a typical He:Ne:CO2 mixture, showing changeover from doppler broadening at low pressures to pressure (collision) broadening above about 10 torr total pressure.

Comment: What does the caption to the figure say? What is the y-axis in plot (c)?